# Google Webmaster Tools reporting lots of server errors due to layered navigation

Tags: layered-navigation, seo

We have noticed recently a big spike in Server Errors being reported in our Google Webmaster Tools crawl errors report.

The bulk of which are returning a 503 response code and whose URLs all seem to be layered navigation urls where some form of sorting has been applied.

My developers have stated that all of these pages have the meta robots tag set to noindex, follow.

They also suggested that they could set these pages to disallow in the Robots.txt file as well, but the links won't be followed on those pages which is bad practice for layered navigation pages.

Anyone have any idea of the best course of action?

Comment: I would suggest that you look into this http://www.manadev.com/seo-layered-navigation-plus -- much better than the magento default layered nav and also it is SEO friendly - I've been using this module on all my projects and never get an issue